# How to assign value in setter of mutableStateOf in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am working in `mutableStateOf`. I want to assign value when initialise the variable. I have one string value which I want to assign in `mutableStateOf`. When string is empty then I don't want to set any value in my `mutableStateOf` variable. I am trying but getting error.

```
val answer: String? = null

var textFieldValue = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())
        set(value) {
            field = value
            if(!answer.isNullOrEmpty()){
                field = answer
            }
        }
```

I am getting error

```
Type mismatch.
Required: MutableState<TextFieldValue>
Found: String
```

I want to set `TextFieldValue()` when my `answer` is null. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
val answer: String? = null
var textFieldValue = mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(answer ?: ""))
```

Comment: I am using `textFieldValue` in viewmodel.